# Opengl 3.3 drivers blender 2.81

Tags: drivers, error, windows, opengl, linux

I use blender 2.81 at start, I get this error, the drivers are updated through the driver pack solution.

[image]

[image]

Some may say that the graphics card is not suitable and needs to be updated. But if I use blender on Ubuntu then the launch there does not give this error and works correctly, tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: I'm not sure what "driver pack" refers to (driver distributed by Microsoft or the vendor of your PC)? Unless you've done that already, download the driver directly from Intel. This will give you the most recent one available that hopefully works.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I looked here
https://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/support/products/80939/graphics-drivers.html
but I don’t know what my generation is, can I find out how?

Comment: Search for your CPU model "[name of your CPU] Intel HD GPU driver". You can find the name in the preferences under the system information.